# Opening default e-mail program with attachment (C#)

Tags: c#, email, interop

I'm looking for a way to open the user's default e-mail program to write a new e-mail and specify an attachment from within a C# application. Right now, I can start an e-mail and specify the recipient, subject, body, etc., but I can't find any way to also specify an attachment.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"mailto:me@mydomain.com&subject=Hi&body=%0D%0DSent from my Kinect");
```

This works great for the basic e-mail, but there's no way to add an attachment. For a bit of background, my boss wants to use voice commands to get a snapshot from the Kinect and then e-mail it to someone.

Looking through the "Question with similar titles", I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784997/launching-email-application-mapi-from-c-with-attachment), which may be the wrong language but it makes me think that there may be a way to at least do it with Microsoft Outlook. That's what the large majority of the people at my work use, but I was really hoping for something that would work with any mail client.

I don't want to just send the e-mail through C#, as I want the user to be able to edit the e-mail within their mail client before sending it.

So, the question: Is there a way to specify an attachment when opening a user's default e-mail program? And if not, where can I find resources on using C# to create an e-mail in Microsoft Outlook with an attachment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open default mail client along with a attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have used the code [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130330033355/http://www.vbusers.com/codecsharp/codeget.asp?ThreadID=71&PostID=1) to open the users default email client with an attachment.

```
// Below is the source code and simple test class for creating and displaying emails. 
// It uses the MAPI API and is therefore not subject to the same restrictions as 
// the "mailto" shell extension.
// 
// Using the MapiMailMessage you can set the title, subject, recipients and attach files. 
// Then show the resulting email to the user, ready from them to send. This class is very 
// useful for supporting applications and enriching addins.
// 
// Note, that the class is a port from a VB version I had and although it does have 
// comments, it is not up to my usual standard. I will be revisiting this and tidying 
// it up shortly.

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

#region Test Class

public class TestMapiMessageClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test method to create and show an email
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MapiMailMessage message = new MapiMailMessage("Test Message", "Test Body");
        message.Recipients.Add("Test@Test.com");
        message.Files.Add(@"C:\del.txt");
        message.ShowDialog();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
#endregion Test Class

#region Public MapiMailMessage Class

/// <summary>
/// Represents an email message to be sent through MAPI.
/// </summary>
public class MapiMailMessage
{
    #region Private MapiFileDescriptor Class

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private class MapiFileDescriptor
    {
        public int reserved = 0;
        public int flags = 0;
        public int position = 0;
        public string path = null;
        public string name = null;
        public IntPtr type = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    #endregion Private MapiFileDescriptor Class

    #region Enums

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the valid RecipientTypes for a Recipient.
    /// </summary>
    public enum RecipientType : int
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Recipient will be in the TO list.
        /// </summary>
        To = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Recipient will be in the CC list.
        /// </summary>
        CC = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// Recipient will be in the BCC list.
        /// </summary>
        BCC = 3
    };

    #endregion Enums

    #region Member Variables

    private string _subject;
    private string _body;
    private RecipientCollection _recipientCollection;
    private ArrayList _files;
    private ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent;

    #endregion Member Variables

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a blank mail message.
    /// </summary>
    public MapiMailMessage()
    {
        _files = new ArrayList();
        _recipientCollection = new RecipientCollection();
        _manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new mail message with the specified subject.
    /// </summary>
    public MapiMailMessage(string subject)
        : this()
    {
        _subject = subject;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new mail message with the specified subject and body.
    /// </summary>
    public MapiMailMessage(string subject, string body)
        : this()
    {
        _subject = subject;
        _body = body;
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the subject of this mail message.
    /// </summary>
    public string Subject
    {
        get { return _subject; }
        set { _subject = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the body of this mail message.
    /// </summary>
    public string Body
    {
        get { return _body; }
        set { _body = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the recipient list for this mail message.
    /// </summary>
    public RecipientCollection Recipients
    {
        get { return _recipientCollection; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the file list for this mail message.
    /// </summary>
    public ArrayList Files
    {
        get { return _files; }
    }

    #endregion Public Properties

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the mail message dialog asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        // Create the mail message in an STA thread
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_ShowMail));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        t.Start();

        // only return when the new thread has built it's interop representation
        _manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
        _manualResetEvent.Reset();
    }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the mail message.
    /// </summary>
    private void _ShowMail(object ignore)
    {
        MAPIHelperInterop.MapiMessage message = new MAPIHelperInterop.MapiMessage();

        using (RecipientCollection.InteropRecipientCollection interopRecipients
                    = _recipientCollection.GetInteropRepresentation())
        {

            message.Subject = _subject;
            message.NoteText = _body;

            message.Recipients = interopRecipients.Handle;
            message.RecipientCount = _recipientCollection.Count;

            // Check if we need to add attachments
            if (_files.Count > 0)
            {
                // Add attachments
                message.Files = _AllocAttachments(out message.FileCount);
            }

            // Signal the creating thread (make the remaining code async)
            _manualResetEvent.Set();

            const int MAPI_DIALOG = 0x8;
            //const int MAPI_LOGON_UI = 0x1;
            const int SUCCESS_SUCCESS = 0;
            int error = MAPIHelperInterop.MAPISendMail(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, message, MAPI_DIALOG, 0);

            if (_files.Count > 0)
            {
                // Deallocate the files
                _DeallocFiles(message);
            }

            // Check for error
            if (error != SUCCESS_SUCCESS)
            {
                _LogErrorMapi(error);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deallocates the files in a message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to deallocate the files from.</param>
    private void _DeallocFiles(MAPIHelperInterop.MapiMessage message)
    {
        if (message.Files != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Type fileDescType = typeof(MapiFileDescriptor);
            int fsize = Marshal.SizeOf(fileDescType);

            // Get the ptr to the files
            int runptr = (int)message.Files;
            // Release each file
            for (int i = 0; i < message.FileCount; i++)
            {
                Marshal.DestroyStructure((IntPtr)runptr, fileDescType);
                runptr += fsize;
            }
            // Release the file
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(message.Files);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allocates the file attachments
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileCount"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IntPtr _AllocAttachments(out int fileCount)
    {
        fileCount = 0;
        if (_files == null)
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        if ((_files.Count <= 0) || (_files.Count > 100))
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        Type atype = typeof(MapiFileDescriptor);
        int asize = Marshal.SizeOf(atype);
        IntPtr ptra = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(_files.Count * asize);

        MapiFileDescriptor mfd = new MapiFileDescriptor();
        mfd.position = -1;
        int runptr = (int)ptra;
        for (int i = 0; i < _files.Count; i++)
        {
            string path = _files[i] as string;
            mfd.name = Path.GetFileName(path);
            mfd.path = path;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(mfd, (IntPtr)runptr, false);
            runptr += asize;
        }

        fileCount = _files.Count;
        return ptra;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the mail message.
    /// </summary>
    private void _ShowMail()
    {
        _ShowMail(null);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Logs any Mapi errors.
    /// </summary>
    private void _LogErrorMapi(int errorCode)
    {
        const int MAPI_USER_ABORT = 1;
        const int MAPI_E_FAILURE = 2;
        const int MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE = 3;
        const int MAPI_E_DISK_FULL = 4;
        const int MAPI_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY = 5;
        const int MAPI_E_BLK_TOO_SMALL = 6;
        const int MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_SESSIONS = 8;
        const int MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_FILES = 9;
        const int MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_RECIPIENTS = 10;
        const int MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_NOT_FOUND = 11;
        const int MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_OPEN_FAILURE = 12;
        const int MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_FAILURE = 13;
        const int MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_RECIPIENT = 14;
        const int MAPI_E_BAD_RECIPTYPE = 15;
        const int MAPI_E_NO_MESSAGES = 16;
        const int MAPI_E_INVALID_MESSAGE = 17;
        const int MAPI_E_TEXT_TOO_LARGE = 18;
        const int MAPI_E_INVALID_SESSION = 19;
        const int MAPI_E_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED = 20;
        const int MAPI_E_AMBIGUOUS_RECIPIENT = 21;
        const int MAPI_E_MESSAGE_IN_USE = 22;
        const int MAPI_E_NETWORK_FAILURE = 23;
        const int MAPI_E_INVALID_EDITFIELDS = 24;
        const int MAPI_E_INVALID_RECIPS = 25;
        const int MAPI_E_NOT_SUPPORTED = 26;
        const int MAPI_E_NO_LIBRARY = 999;
        const int MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER = 998;

        string error = string.Empty;
        switch (errorCode)
        {
            case MAPI_USER_ABORT:
                error = "User Aborted.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_FAILURE:
                error = "MAPI Failure.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE:
                error = "Login Failure.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_DISK_FULL:
                error = "MAPI Disk full.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY:
                error = "MAPI Insufficient memory.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_BLK_TOO_SMALL:
                error = "MAPI Block too small.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_SESSIONS:
                error = "MAPI Too many sessions.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_FILES:
                error = "MAPI too many files.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_RECIPIENTS:
                error = "MAPI too many recipients.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_NOT_FOUND:
                error = "MAPI Attachment not found.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_OPEN_FAILURE:
                error = "MAPI Attachment open failure.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_FAILURE:
                error = "MAPI Attachment Write Failure.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_RECIPIENT:
                error = "MAPI Unknown recipient.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_BAD_RECIPTYPE:
                error = "MAPI Bad recipient type.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_NO_MESSAGES:
                error = "MAPI No messages.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_INVALID_MESSAGE:
                error = "MAPI Invalid message.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_TEXT_TOO_LARGE:
                error = "MAPI Text too large.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_INVALID_SESSION:
                error = "MAPI Invalid session.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                error = "MAPI Type not supported.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_AMBIGUOUS_RECIPIENT:
                error = "MAPI Ambiguous recipient.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_MESSAGE_IN_USE:
                error = "MAPI Message in use.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_NETWORK_FAILURE:
                error = "MAPI Network failure.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_INVALID_EDITFIELDS:
                error = "MAPI Invalid edit fields.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_INVALID_RECIPS:
                error = "MAPI Invalid Recipients.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                error = "MAPI Not supported.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_NO_LIBRARY:
                error = "MAPI No Library.";
                break;
            case MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                error = "MAPI Invalid parameter.";
                break;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Error sending MAPI Email. Error: " + error + " (code = " + errorCode + ").");
    }
    #endregion Private Methods

    #region Private MAPIHelperInterop Class

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal class for calling MAPI APIs
    /// </summary>
    internal class MAPIHelperInterop
    {
        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Private constructor.
        /// </summary>
        private MAPIHelperInterop()
        {
            // Intenationally blank
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Constants

        public const int MAPI_LOGON_UI = 0x1;

        #endregion Constants

        #region APIs

        [DllImport("MAPI32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int MAPILogon(IntPtr hwnd, string prf, string pw, int flg, int rsv, ref IntPtr sess);

        #endregion APIs

        #region Structs

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
            public class MapiMessage
        {
            public int Reserved = 0;
            public string Subject = null;
            public string NoteText = null;
            public string MessageType = null;
            public string DateReceived = null;
            public string ConversationID = null;
            public int Flags = 0;
            public IntPtr Originator = IntPtr.Zero;
            public int RecipientCount = 0;
            public IntPtr Recipients = IntPtr.Zero;
            public int FileCount = 0;
            public IntPtr Files = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
            public class MapiRecipDesc
        {
            public int Reserved = 0;
            public int RecipientClass = 0;
            public string Name = null;
            public string Address = null;
            public int eIDSize = 0;
            public IntPtr EntryID = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        [DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")]
        public static extern int MAPISendMail(IntPtr session, IntPtr hwnd, MapiMessage message, int flg, int rsv);

        #endregion Structs
    }

    #endregion Private MAPIHelperInterop Class
}

#endregion Public MapiMailMessage Class

#region Public Recipient Class

/// <summary>
/// Represents a Recipient for a MapiMailMessage.
/// </summary>
public class Recipient
{
    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The email address of this recipient.
    /// </summary>
    public string Address = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The display name of this recipient.
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayName = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// How the recipient will receive this message (To, CC, BCC).
    /// </summary>
    public MapiMailMessage.RecipientType RecipientType = MapiMailMessage.RecipientType.To;

    #endregion Public Properties

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new recipient with the specified address.
    /// </summary>
    public Recipient(string address)
    {
        Address = address;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new recipient with the specified address and display name.
    /// </summary>
    public Recipient(string address, string displayName)
    {
        Address = address;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new recipient with the specified address and recipient type.
    /// </summary>
    public Recipient(string address, MapiMailMessage.RecipientType recipientType)
    {
        Address = address;
        RecipientType = recipientType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new recipient with the specified address, display name and recipient type.
    /// </summary>
    public Recipient(string address, string displayName, MapiMailMessage.RecipientType recipientType)
    {
        Address = address;
        DisplayName = displayName;
        RecipientType = recipientType;
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Internal Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an interop representation of a recepient.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal MapiMailMessage.MAPIHelperInterop.MapiRecipDesc GetInteropRepresentation()
    {
        MapiMailMessage.MAPIHelperInterop.MapiRecipDesc interop = new MapiMailMessage.MAPIHelperInterop.MapiRecipDesc();

        if (DisplayName == null)
        {
            interop.Name = Address;
        }
        else
        {
            interop.Name = DisplayName;
            interop.Address = Address;
        }

        interop.RecipientClass = (int)RecipientType;

        return interop;
    }

    #endregion Internal Methods
}

#endregion Public Recipient Class

#region Public RecipientCollection Class

/// <summary>
/// Represents a colleciton of recipients for a mail message.
/// </summary>
public class RecipientCollection : CollectionBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified recipient to this collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(Recipient value)
    {
        List.Add(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new recipient with the specified address to this collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(string address)
    {
        this.Add(new Recipient(address));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new recipient with the specified address and display name to this collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(string address, string displayName)
    {
        this.Add(new Recipient(address, displayName));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new recipient with the specified address and recipient type to this collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(string address, MapiMailMessage.RecipientType recipientType)
    {
        this.Add(new Recipient(address, recipientType));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new recipient with the specified address, display name and recipient type to this collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(string address, string displayName, MapiMailMessage.RecipientType recipientType)
    {
        this.Add(new Recipient(address, displayName, recipientType));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the recipient stored in this collection at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    public Recipient this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Recipient)List[index];
        }
    }

    internal InteropRecipientCollection GetInteropRepresentation()
    {
        return new InteropRecipientCollection(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Struct which contains an interop representation of a colleciton of recipients.
    /// </summary>
    internal struct InteropRecipientCollection : IDisposable
    {
        #region Member Variables

        private IntPtr _handle;
        private int _count;

        #endregion Member Variables

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor for creating InteropRecipientCollection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="outer"></param>
        public InteropRecipientCollection(RecipientCollection outer)
        {
            _count = outer.Count;

            if (_count == 0)
            {
                _handle = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }

            // allocate enough memory to hold all recipients
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MapiMailMessage.MAPIHelperInterop.MapiRecipDesc));
            _handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(_count * size);

            // place all interop recipients into the memory just allocated
            int ptr = (int)_handle;
            foreach (Recipient native in outer)
            {
                MapiMailMessage.MAPIHelperInterop.MapiRecipDesc interop = native.GetInteropRepresentation();

                // stick it in the memory block
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(interop, (IntPtr)ptr, false);
                ptr += size;
            }
        }

        #endregion Costructors

        #region Public Properties

        public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get { return _handle; }
        }

        #endregion Public Properties

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes of resources.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Type type = typeof(MapiMailMessage.MAPIHelperInterop.MapiRecipDesc);
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(type);

                // destroy all the structures in the memory area
                int ptr = (int)_handle;
                for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
                {
                    Marshal.DestroyStructure((IntPtr)ptr, type);
                    ptr += size;
                }

                // free the memory
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_handle);

                _handle = IntPtr.Zero;
                _count = 0;
            }
        }

        #endregion Public Methods
    }
}

#endregion Public RecipientCollection Class
```

Comment: @beater unfortunately the link seems to be dead - can you provide an update?

Comment: Link via wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20130330033355/http://www.vbusers.com/codecsharp/codeget.asp?ThreadID=71&PostID=1

Comment: After years of working great, this has just stopped working. It will crash during the ShowDialog() method. Any ideas?

Comment: Ive just got this working. There are a few instances of int that caused an overflow. I changed these to Int64 which seems to have resolved it

Comment: Now any usage of this code or usage of MapiSendMail or MapiSendMailW ends with error 'There is no email program associated to perform the requested action...' :( Seems broken in modern Windows versions with default email client (Mail from MS Store) installed

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do exactly what you need, theres a number of issues from security concerns to automatically mailing attachments via a client that needs a username/password to not being able to send keys as your trying to cope with any number of email clients.

An alternative though, as you know you can send an email by C#, with an attachment. What about creating an email that gets sent to the user that they can forward with their own edits ?

Comment: Great idea for the alternative, will definitely keep that in mind in case I can't get this working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify attachments with the `mailto:` url handler.

Comment: I know, I'm looking for alternatives where I can use attachments.